# How to make a generic type optional in Dart?

Tags: dart, generics

I have a class that uses a generic type parameter, but I want to make it optional so that it can be specified or omitted. How can I do this in Dart?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class MyClass<T?> {

}

void main() {
  var myObject1 = MyClass<String>();
  var myObject2 = MyClass(); // generic type is optional and defaults to dynamic
}
```

However, when I try to run this code, I get a syntax error on the question mark (?) after the type parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Generic type arguments are already optional and default to `dynamic` if you do not specify type constraints. That is, `class MyClass<T>` already does what you want.

Comment: if there are multiple generic arguments. how to make some of them optional?

Comment: Generic type arguments must either all be specified or none at all.  Unfortunately, Dart does not allow specifying some but not all of them.  In some cases, this can be worked around by making a class take one generic type argument and its method another or by using [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved through normal use of type arguments. When a type argument is omitted, the most permissive type is used.

```dart
class Class1<T> { }
class Class2<T extends Object> { }
class Class3<T extends num> { }

void main() {
  Class1<String>(); // Class1<String>
  Class1();         // Class1<dynamic>

  Class2<String>(); // Class2<String>
  Class2();         // Class2<Object> (non-nullable!)

  Class3<String>(); // Compile-time error
  Class3<int>();    // Class3<int>
  Class3();         // Class3<num>
};
```